# php http_build_query error "0="

Tags: php

hi iam using this code to post the url and get result but its adding =0 before every result

my code is

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<h1>In this demonstration:<br />
>tts is done on server side (i.e by using Google-translate server)<br/>
>then the audio received from Google-translate server is saved on your server (local/production)<br />
>and then that saved audio is played through that saved file on this webpage.</h1>
<h3>
Tested with:
Chrome v21 [Working],
Firefox v14 [Not Working, firefox does not support mp3 audio format playback],
IE v9[Working]
</h3>
<hr />
<form method="POST">
Text to convert : <input name="txt" type="text" /><br />
Filename to save (without the extension) : <input name="filename" type="text" /><br />
Convert text to speech : <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Convert" />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['txt']) && isset($_POST['filename']))
{
    $text=htmlentities($_POST['txt']);
    $filename=$_POST['filename'].'.mp3';

    $querystring = http_build_query(array($text));

    if ($soundfile = file_get_contents("http://api.voicerss.org?key=c68635f1104b452e8dbe740c0c0330f3&src=$querystring&hl=en-in j"))
    {
        file_put_contents($filename,$soundfile);
        echo ('
            <audio autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">
            <source src="'.$filename.'" type="audio/mp3" />
            </audio>
            <br />
            Saved mp3 location : '.dirname(__FILE__).'\\'.$filename.'
            <br />
            Saved mp3 uri : <a href="'.$filename.'">'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/webtts/'.$filename.'</a>'
        );
    }
    else echo("<br />Audio could not be saved");
}
?>
```

Its result is 
http://api.voicerss.org?key=c68635f1104b452e8dbe740c0c0330f3&src=0=Good+evening.+Please+sit+down.+Now+tell+me+about+your+problem&hl=en-in

It should not show src=0=Good, it should show src=Good+evening,  how to remove 0=

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to supply an associative array to http_build_query

So change

```
 http_build_query(array($text))
```

to

```
 http_build_query(array("src"=>$text))
```

and

```
 file_get_contents("http://api.voicerss.org?key=c68635f1104b452e8dbe740c0c0330f3&src=$querystring&hl=en-in j
```

to

```
file_get_contents("http://api.voicerss.org?key=c68635f1104b452e8dbe740c0c0330f3&$querystring&hl=en-in j
```

Alternatively you can use

```
http_build_query(array(
     "src"=>$text,
     "key"=>"c68635f1104b452e8dbe740c0c0330f3",
     "hl"=>"en-in j"))
```

and

```
file_get_contents("http://api.voicerss.org?".$querystring);
```

Comment: @ShiveshJaiswal If you found this answer to be helpful click the check by the answer title to accept it and close out the question.